# Netbeans subversion can't commit files

Tags: svn, netbeans, commit

I'm quite new to Netbeans, but not to versioning controll. Still it seems to be impossible for me to simply commit changes... Let me explain.

I just reïnstalled Netbeans 6.9.1, including the right Subversion plugins. I use the build in SVN client (since TortoiseSVN doesn't work with netbeans..). I downloaded my repository from my SVN server, and updated everything to be sure (did both twice...). I even rebooted to be sure.

But everytime I want to commit changes, Netbeans shows me a dialog where no files are selected. When I check show changes, the changes are shown but when I commit, the files aren't there.

My teammates can commit and have no problems (they're using another SVN client, but I don't want to have 3 different SVN clients on my pc...).

I can update and see changes but svn won't let me commit changes. Does anyone know a solution to my problem?

To clarify:

When I mousOver my project file it says that I have changes:

http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/6042/containschanges.png

When I try to commit it says there are no changes:

http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/384/nofilestocommit.png

Comment: What happens if you diff your working copy with TortoiseSVN or the command line client? Do you have any diff then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by 'diff'. But maybe this answers your question: if I use TortoiseSVN (without netbeans) I can commit changes from my working copy, but TortoiseSVN doesn't seem to reckognize the working copy made by Netbeans

Answer (score 1):

I see this problem as well with Netbeans 6.9.1 running on Mac OS X 10.5.  I've seen several false leads, and let me tell you what will not work.  Doing a svn cleanup will not fix this problem.  Changing svn clients will not fix this problem.  Changing svn release versions will not fix this problem.  Issuing a "svn commit"  from any cllient outside of Netbeans will successfully commit the file and Netbeans will pick up the change in status and report it (Change the color from blue to black) almost immediately.

It might have to do with a bug in Netbeans where switching a project to Mercurial and then switching back to svn leaves the GUI in a corrupted state.

My next step is to check in all changes on the command line, do a completely fresh install of Netbeans in a new user account, and configure it to checkout my repository.  Just thought this info might be helpful.  No one else has said anything except Albin.